# How to record visited constants by MethodVisitor in ASM

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to check how many times a constant is used in the given classes. My idea is to first use ClassReader.accept(ClassVisitor, ...) to visit the class, and then declare a methodVisitor for each method using MethodVisitor.visitMethod(). Then, for each MethodVisitor, I tried to use visitFieldInsn. However, this method never visits constants. Instead, every other non-constant variables are visited.

Here's my code:

```
import org.objectweb.asm.*;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ASMVisitor {

    static class SimpleMethodVisitor extends MethodVisitor {
        public String currMethodName;
        public List<String[]> constants = new ArrayList<>();
        private final Map<Object, Integer> constantFrequencyMap;

        public SimpleMethodVisitor(int api, MethodVisitor methodVisitor, String methodName) {
            super(Opcodes.ASM9, methodVisitor);
            currMethodName = methodName;
            constantFrequencyMap = new HashMap<>();
        }

        @Override
        public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, java.lang.String owner, java.lang.String name, java.lang.String descriptor, boolean isInterface) {
//            System.out.println(Opcodes.LDC);

//            System.out.println("Visited method instruction: " + opcode + ", " + owner + ", " + name + ", " + descriptor + ", " + isInterface);
            super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, descriptor, isInterface);
        }

        public Map<Object, Integer> getConstantFrequencyMap() {
            return constantFrequencyMap;
        }

        @Override
        public void visitLdcInsn(Object cst) {
//            System.out.println("Method " + this.currMethodName + " contains ldc instruction: " + cst);
            super.visitLdcInsn(cst);
        }

        @Override
        public void visitInsn(int opcode) {
            System.out.println("Method " + this.currMethodName + " contains instruction: " + opcode);
            super.visitInsn(opcode);
        }

        @Override
        public void visitFieldInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String descriptor) {
            System.out.printf("FieldInsn: opcode = %s, Owner = %s, Name = %s, Descriptor = %s\n",
                    opcode, owner, name, descriptor);
            constants.add(new String[]{owner, name, descriptor});
        }

    }

    static class SimpleClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {
        public String currClassName;
        public Map<String[],Object> constants;
        public Set<MethodVisitor> mvs = new HashSet<>();

        public SimpleClassVisitor() {
            super(Opcodes.ASM9);
            currClassName = "";
            this.constants = new HashMap<>();
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(int version, int acc, String name,
                                    String sig, String superName, String[] ifs) {
            currClassName = name;
            super.visit(version, acc, name, sig, superName, ifs);
        }

        @Override
        public FieldVisitor visitField(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, Object value) {
            System.out.printf("visitField: Name = %s, Desc = %s, Signature = %s, Value = %s\n",
                    name, desc, signature, value);

            if (value != null && (access & Opcodes.ACC_STATIC) != 0) {
                constants.put(new String[]{currClassName, name, desc}, value);
            }

            return super.visitField(access, name, desc, signature, value);
        }

        @Override
        public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
//            System.out.printf("visitMethod: Name = %s, Desc = %s, Signature = %s\n", name, desc, signature);
            MethodVisitor methodvisitor = super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
            MethodVisitor mv = new SimpleMethodVisitor(Opcodes.ASM9, methodvisitor, name);
            mvs.add(mv);
            return mv;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            ...
            try {
                byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file);
                ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(bytes);
                SimpleClassVisitor scv = new SimpleClassVisitor();
                classReader.accept(scv, ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES | ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my dummy test

```
package DummyTests2;

public class DummyTest1 {
    public int publicIVInteger1;
    public static int notFinal = -1;
    public final int notStatic = -1;
    public static final int dummy0 = 0;
    public static final int dummy1 = -1;

    public DummyTest1() {
        this.publicIVInteger1 = DummyTest2.dummy1;
        getPublicIVInteger1();
    }

    public int getPublicIVInteger1() {
        setPublicIVInteger1(1);
        notFinal -= dummy1;
        notFinal -= dummy0;
        publicIVInteger1 -= dummy1;
        publicIVInteger1 -= dummy0;

        return this.publicIVInteger1;
    }

    public void setPublicIVInteger1(int n) {
        int localInt = 0;
        publicIVInteger1 += dummy1;
    }
}
```

In this case, only variables that are not constants are printed out without those constants with static and final like dummy0 and dummy1. I also tried to use visitInsn and seems like constants are visited since the corresponding instructions are visited, but the visitLdcInsn is never visited too. I wonder why constants are not recognized for visitFieldInsn and how can I do to store the frequency of constants into the constantFrequencyMap.

Comment: What happens if your constants are not capable of being embedded in the opcode, say 999999 or -123456?

Comment: I don't think this caused the issue since the printed message from visitInsn() tells that the opcode is only 2 and 3 for dummy0 and dummy1

Comment: When you use compile-time constants in Java, the compiled code will use the constant value directly. Therefore, you can not distinguish between uses of `dummy1`, `notStatic`, or literal `-1` in the compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

As someone said in a comment primitive constants will be inlined as a literal in bytecode, so:

```java
public static final int TEST_CONST = 11;

private static void bar() {
    System.out.println(TEST_CONST);
}
```

Would compile to

```java
public static final int TEST_CONST = 11;

private static void bar() {
    System.out.println(11);
}
```

However non primitive constants will still have a `GETSTATIC` reference, for the primitives the best you could do is collect all primitive constants beforehand and then try to guess if a literal is referring to one of them by comparing their values, however this is far from perfect.

Comment: Tried it with the non-primitive constant `final String foo = "foo";`. Was inlined.

Comment: Strings are technically still primitives, since in case of constants and literals in bytecode there will be a single LDC instruction, that''s also the reason why you can use them in annotations.

Comment: Not exactly. I can load anything with an ldc, and arrays - which can't be constant - can be used in an annotation as well. Those things are not related at all.

Comment: In this specific case the ldc instructions simply functions as quicker internal way of putting a string literal on the stack, I am aware that it can do more than that but in this context it doesn't matter. It gets inlined because it is a single instruction putting the value on the stack and not an actual object construction via a new and invokespecial. If you want my answer to explicitly state that every constant that is inlined as literal will be equal to a single bytecode instruction feel free to edit, I'll gratefully approve it

Comment: Coincidence does not imply causality. A class literal like `Thread.class` within an expression will be compiled to a single `ldc` instruction, further, class literals are allowed in annotations. Also `Class` objects are never created via `new`/`invokespecial`. Still, class literals are not compile-time constants and there’s no inlining behavior. Compile-time constants are [well defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29): “*A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type **or** a String …*”. A `String` is not a primitive value.